# Can Rogue's mutant siphoning power sustain her, or does she need to eat?

Tags: marvel, rogue

The X-Man Rogue's central ability is bio-energy absorption via tactile contact on her skin. Done for too long on another being, she can absorb their "life energy", and in the case of other super beings, keep their powers permanently, as she did with Carol Danvers.

As this is a form of bio-energy, however, can Rogue use it to sustain herself in lieu of the chemical energy of food?

Is there any source or example that says she "needs" to eat, or could she just touch someone for a few seconds and get all the energy she needs to keep herself going daily?

Comment: Deficiency diseases seem likely...

Comment: @ZeissIkon that too seems unclear, Z. When Rogue, both film and comic book version, absorbs a mutants energy, she takes some of their current strength and abilities, as well. I'm not 100% certain of the mechanics of how this works, but for their vitality to be so high, deficiencies might not be a big issue. Hell, with her Cree-influenced physiology from Ms. Marvel, we're not even certain if she is _able_ to suffer from such deficiencies!  Which actually gives me an idea for a whole new question....thanks, pal!